# What is the difference between Drupal Answers and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I've only just noticed the existence of Drupal Answers. In what way is Drupal Answers not redundant with questions on Stack Overflow with the Drupal tag?

I mean, I realize that some "traditional" developers might look down on Drupal developers because a Drupal site doesn't require writing as much source code as other frameworks, but it's still programming nonetheless. I think this is quite the slippery slope---at what point do we start creating new Stack Exchange sites for all frameworks?

Assuming you don't care if Drupal is getting special treatment, here, what types of questions should be posted on Drupal Answers that cannot be asked on Stack Overflow or Server Fault, and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Drupal Answers* is a Q&A site specifically for Drupal questions. The difference with *Stack Overflow* is that, strictly speaking, the latter is only for programming questions or for questions about programming tools, and Drupal is not (strictly speaking) a programming tool. You should ask on *Stack Overflow* questions related to Drupal programming, while you should not ask questions about which module to install in your Drupal site.

The truth is that questions you ask on *Drupal Answers* are still on topic on *Stack Overflow* (but not vice versa); the difference between *Stack Overflow* and *Drupal Answers* is the same difference that there is between [Super User](http://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com): you can ask questions about Apple software in both the Q&A sites, but some questions are thought to better suit *Ask Different*.
The fact some questions have been migrated from *Stack Overflow* to *Drupal Answers* means that some questions are thought to better suit *Drupal Answers*.

See also what reported in [Which questions should be on-topic on Drupal Answers, but not on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87719/which-questions-should-be-on-topic-on-drupal-answers-but-not-on-stack-overflow)
For a different point of view, see also the first comment (written by a *Stack Overflow* moderator) to [Merge the "drupal-theme" and the "drupal-themes" tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86173/merge-the-drupal-theme-and-the-drupal-themes-tags), which reports:

> The tag should be deleted. All questions re [drupal-theme] should go to the drupal.SE site.

Comment: While I disagree with your notion that Drupal is not a programming tool, your answer works for me. I do think it is a little bit sad that there are so many niche Stack Exchange sites popping up, though.

I particularly liked the question [When will Stack Overflow become irrelevant?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84249/when-will-stack-overflow-become-irrelevant) that you led me to by proxy.